# how to execute command from custom webmin module as non root

Tags: linux, webmin

i've created a small custom module for webmin, the module perform copy move and other file operation using perl command as well as external bash script that create move or delete files.
I'd like to run all this as non root user (From what i understood all this run as root because the webmin service is started as root)
Is there a way to configure the module to execute everything as the login user used or even as a specific user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my notes I have

```
switch_to_remote_user()
```

to become the remote login in a Usermin module, but it's a long time since I wrote a webmin module, so that's the only clue I can give.

---

Perhaps you can just use standard perl. If you know the userid (i.e. the number, eg 1000) that
you want to switch the effective user to, do `$> = 1000;`.
You can lookup the number from a name using `$uid = getpwnam($name);`.

Comment: I added how to set the effective id in perl.

Comment: no joy also with this, will try give more try and see if i missed anything but seems webmin keep execute all as root

Comment: the switch_to_remote_user works at least on a later wversion of webmin than the one i used initially